# Check if getops argument is of a certain type

Tags: bash

I'm completely new with bash so I don't know how most things work. 
I have this code which works when I enter the right type of arguments, but I need that the argument that goes with the -a flag can only be a string of letters and that the argument that goes with the -b flag can only be a string of numbers. Otherwise it should give an error message and exit.

```
while getopts a:b flag; do
    case "${flag}" in
        a) times=${OPTARG};;
        b) type=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

java -jar TestSort.jar $times $type
```

should I create a function that checks every character of the argument string?

Comment: `bash` only has one type: string.

Comment: @chepner yes but I want to check if the string is numeric or not

Comment: That seems like something you should let `TestSort.jar` worry about.

Comment: @chepner alright thank you!